# Sony Spresense 拡張ボード取り外し方法

Tags: spresense

Spresenseのメインボードを拡張ボードから取り外したいのですが、手法をご教示いただきたく
よろしくお願いいたします。

接続は以下の通りに実施しました。
https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/hardware-overview#_spresense%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%A8spresense%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95

Comment: ご回答いただき誠にありがとうございます。一つづつピンをペンチでつまみつつ押すことで無事取り外すことができました。
本当に助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

拡張ボード側の爪の部分を指で強めに閉じて、そのまま穴に向けて押し出すようにすると取れますよ。

一つ一つを一度に無理に取ろうとせず、四つのスペーサを順々に少しずつ押し出すのがポイントです。最初はかなり苦労しますがコツを覚えると簡単に出来るようになります。

試してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

質問に書かれているURLのページに
　　『接続後はメインボードと拡張ボードを無理に取り外さないように注意してください』
との注意書きがありますから、"メーカー推奨の取り外し方"のようなものはないのだと思います。

二つのボードを物理的につなぐスペーサーはプラスチック製のように見えますので、薄刃のプラスチックモデル用ニッパーなどを用いて中央部を切断した後に、２つのボードを電気的につなぐコネクタを真っすぐに引き抜くのが、基板やコネクタへのダメージが少ない(無理が少ない)のではないかと思います。